# Faraday's Law - When do we know when it is a motional EMF or an induced electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

So from what I know, Faraday's law states that when there is a change in magnetic flux, an EMF is induced.

This can be explained with motional EMF where when the magnet moves towards the conducting loop, in the reference frame of the magnet, the conducting loop is actually moving towards it. Hence, motional EMF can be applied where the magnetic force causes the charges to move, hence EMF is induced.

However, there is also the explanation of changing magnetic fields induces non-conservative curling electric fields according to Maxwell's equations, hence when there is a conducting loop, this induced electric field causes a the charges to move, hence EMF is induced.

My question is, how can we differentiate these 2 completely different scenarios from each other? Or are they the same scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially different scenarios having the same explanation to them. According to Lenz's law, the induced current produced in a circuit always flows in such a direction that it opposes the change or cause that produced it. The change referred to here is a change in the magnetic flux.

Now, when we consider the motional EMF case, the magnet moving towards the loop causes an increase in the magnetic flux passing through the loop. So naturally, a current is induced that opposes this change (kind of like inertia). Now, it's important to note that in this case too, induced electric fields are produced. This can be explained by the fact that induced current is produced by nothing other than induced electric fields, and hence, whenever there is induced current know that there exists an induced electric field in the same direction as the current at every point.

So, since both have induced electric fields, it's basically the same explanation.

Comment: So is the induced current in the motional EMF due to induced electric fields or the magnetic force on the charges?

Comment: The term 'magnetic force' is just a general way of referring to a force produced by a magnetic field. Search up 'Lorentz Force derivation' and you'll find how the expression $e=vcrossBdotl$ came into existence. Spoiler: it's caused by an induced electric field within the conductor.

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much for clarifying my doubts!

Comment: Hi, I can't find proof of how the e = bvl has anything to do with induced electric field. Could you direct me to your source?

Comment: Oh, wait. I meant that motional EMF was caused by induced electric fields, which can be explained using Lorentz force. Ykw, I'll just explain it to you.

Comment: Suppose a vertical conducting rod that is moving from the left side of the screen towards the right.  Let there be a magnetic field directed into the plane of the screen. Now, since a conducting rod will have a lot of free electrons, and since they're moving in the presence of a magnetic field, they experience Lorentz Force. By Fleming's left hand rule, this force causes electrons to move upwards in the conductor itself. Hence, there is a negative charge at the top of the rod and a positive charge at the bottom.

Comment: This induced electric field causes a potential difference to arise between the top and bottom parts of the rod, since $E.l=V$. Hence an EMF is induced.

Comment: Uhmm I think you are confusing this electrostatic field with induced electric field. This field that you just described is actually a conservative field which is an electrostatic field. The field which Im referring to which only applies to Maxwell's equations is the non-conservative induced electric field which curls.

Comment: Oh. yes. I kind of forgot what the original question even was lol. There's another explanation for motional EMF: through Faraday's laws. Consider this moving rod to be attached to two wires, hence forming a loop (imagine a square loop; the two wires are connected to the ends to the rod). Now when this rod moves, the area in the loop is increasing, hence flux is increasing since the rod is placed in a uniform magnetic field. therefore, an induced electric is produced according to Lenz' Law.

Comment: You might wonder how this loop is indefinitely extensible. Just think that there is a really long wire bent into a rectangle with one missing side and the rod is that missing side, only it's connected not at the ends of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how can we differentiate these 2 completely different scenarios from each other? Or are they the same scenarios?

They are different descriptions of the same phenomenon, because they describe it in different frames of reference.

In the frame of the magnet, where the magnet is static and the wire moves, the mobile free charges in the wire experience *electromotive forces* due to rest of the moving wire, and these do work on the current; energy for this comes from the kinetic energy of the wire (or in case the wire is not slowing down, from the work of force maintaining its motion).

In the frame where the wire is static and the magnet moves, the current in the wire experiences *induced electric field of the magnet*. It does work on the current, and energy for this comes from the kinetic energy of the magnet (or in case the magnet is not slowing down, from the work of force maintaining its motion).